# Vb programming debugging run time error

Tags: vba, excel, debugging

I'm totally new to VBA in excel. Below is my code and whenever I try to run it, it says:

> "Run time Error'424': Object required".

I Don't know what to do, can anyone help me with this?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim a, b, LastRow1, LastRow2 As Integer

LastRow1 = Sheets("BOM2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastRow2 = Sheets("SKU").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For a = 2 To LastRow1
 For b = 2 To LastRow2

If Sheets("BOM2").Cells(a, "D").Value = Sheets("SKU").Cells(b, "D").Value Then
  Sheets("SKU").Cells(b, "D").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Final").Range("A" & Row.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

End If
Next b
Next a

End Sub
```

Comment: Your `Dim` statement probably doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Best practise is `Dim a As long, b As long, LastRow1 As long, LastRow2 As long` . Without explicitly declaring each type you are implicitly declaring *a, b,* and *LastRow1* as variant type variables. Always use *long* for variables intended to refer to worksheet rows.

Comment: It's a good idea to include a mention as to which line of code generates the error.

Comment: Thanks man, don't know how to debug it so it shows the error but now it's working tnx

Answer (score 0):

```
Range("A" & Row.Count)
```

should be

```
Range("A" & Rows.Count)
```